# Getting rid of extra printing in subprocess Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, subprocess, ip

I am trying to print my ip address using subprocess.run() in Linux. So , i wrote the following code:

```
ip=subprocess.run(["ifconfig | grep -w 'inet' | awk '{print $2}' | head -n 1"],shell=True,)
```

It gives me my Ip address "192.168.1.103" in terminal , but i wrote it "print(ip)" , it gives me : "CompletedProcess(args=["ifconfig | grep -w 'inet' | awk '{print $2}' | head -n 1"], returncode=0)"

I want the result ,i.e "192.168.1.103" when i wrote print(ip). So how can i do it ? Moreover when i wrote the followings in Pycharm , it gives me similar reply :

**The code:**

```
ip=subprocess.run(["ifconfig | grep -w 'inet' | awk '{print $2}' | head -n 1"],shell=True,)
print(ip)
```

**The result:**

```
192.168.1.103
CompletedProcess(args=["ifconfig | grep -w 'inet' | awk '{print $2}' | head -n 1"], returncode=0)
```

How can I obtain only Ip address without printing "CompletedProcess(args=["ifconfig | grep -w 'inet' | awk '{print $2}' | head -n 1"], returncode=0)" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save it to a temporary text file and load it back to the program like this:

```
import subprocess

ip=subprocess.run(["ifconfig | grep -w 'inet' | awk '{print $2}' | head -n 1"],shell=True, capture_output=True)
print((ip.stdout).decode('ascii').strip())
```

**Output**

```
"192.168.1.200"
```

Comment: thanks but it prolongs the code , i am looking for some property in subprocess module

Comment: here you are, hope that is what you're looking for

Comment: i tried to upvote but because of low reputation , i can only accept the answer